# Regexp fails to match UTF-8 characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, unicode, utf-8

Given the following UTF-8 text in Notepad++:

```
 1
☺ ☺️ 2
 3
```

Both `^[^ ]+` and `^[\S]+` match only the second line.

The same expressions matches all 3 lines in Visual Studio 2019.

What am I missing?

Comment: What encoding do you have set in the text file?

Comment: I think lines 1 & 3  contain UTF-32, not UTF-8

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8, tried with ANSI, also didn't work.  The lines are UTF-8 emoji.

Comment: Notepad++ UTF8 support is very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that NP++ has problems when searching for Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual plane (BMP) that have a code-point between `\x{10000}` and `\x{10FFFF}` (greater than `\x{FFFF}`).

A workaround is to use surrogate pairs.

Apparently a limitation of the Boost Regex.

Source: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19990/regexp-fails-to-match-utf-8-characters/